# Not able to perform swipe or scroll using JavaScript Executor in IOS WebView

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

We are trying to automate a scenario where we need to perform scroll operation, but swipe & JavaScriptExecutor is not working, a little background to our problem, the application under test is a hybrid application (both native & webview are available) and we are using IOS_Webkit_Debug_Proxy to enable web_view. (We are not using native elements as our application is total built on webview)

Tried couple of ways like switching web_view to native and vice versa but in both the cases driver.swipe method or scroll application using JavaScript Executor is not working.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, 
configuration.getProperty(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME));
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, configuration.getProperty(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION));
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,configuration.getProperty(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME));
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, configuration.getProperty(Constants.UDID));capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,8000); 
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, System.getProperty("user.dir") + configuration.getProperty(Constants.APP_IOS));    
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTO_WEBVIEW, true);
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);   
String urlString = new 
StringBuffer(configuration.getProperty(Constants.PROTOCOL)).append("://".append(configuration.getProperty(Constants.HOST_NAME)).append(":").append(configuration.getProperty(Constants.PORT)).append("/wd/hub").toString(); 
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Constants.TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,TimeUnit.SECONDS);'


JavaClient: 4.1.2
Appium: 1.6.4
IOS_Webkit_Debug_Proxy
IOS version: 10.2
```

xCode: 8.3.2
Physical Device
Let me know if you require more details and we are in the middle of the project we need solution or workaround to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the TouchAction class from java client.

This may help you out:

```
public void swipeWithTouch(){

    TouchAction action = new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver);
    action.longPress(fromX, fromY).moveTo(toX, toY).release().perform();
}
```